# MVC 3 Razor - How to handle success/error messages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, error-handling

I am using MVC3 for a new project and I am able to pass the values from my model to my DAL and successfully submit data to the database. Being new to MVC I am not sure how to handle success and error messages.

What I want to do is give the user some feedback after the form is submitted and I don't know if I am meant to create a new controller for this or reuse my current controller but write some logic in the view to hide the form and show the message.

**ActionResult CreateUser is the form and ActionResult CreateUser with httppost handles form submission**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using UserManager.Models;

namespace UserManager.Controllers
{
    public class UserManagerController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /UserManager/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            try
            {
                var data = new UserManager.Models.UserManagerTestEntities();
                return View(data.vw_UserManager_Model_Add_Users.ToList());

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return View(ViewBag);
            }

        }


        public ActionResult LookUpGroupName(string q, int limit)
        {
            //TODO: Map list to autocomplete textbox control
            DAL d = new DAL();
            List<string> groups = d.groups();

            var GroupValue = groups
                .Where(x => x.Contains(q))
                .OrderBy(x => x)
                .Take(limit)
                .Select(r => new { group = r });

            // Return the result set as JSON
            return Json(GroupValue, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }


        public ActionResult CreateUser()
        {
            //var data = new UserManager.Models.UserManagerTestEntities();
            ViewBag.Message = "Create New User";
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CreateUser(vw_UserManager_Model_Add_Users newUser)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    //var data = new UserManager.Models.UserManagerTestEntities();
                    // Pass model to Data Layer
                    List<string> outcome =  UserManager.DAL.CreateUser(newUser);
                    //data.SaveChanges();
                }
                return View();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return View(ex.ToString());
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**My DAL**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using UserManager.Models;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace UserManager
{
    public class DAL
    {
        #region hashingpassword
        private static string CreateSalt(int size)
        {
            // Generate a cryptographic random number.
            RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] buff = new byte[size];
            rng.GetBytes(buff);

            // Return a Base64 string representation of the random number.
            return Convert.ToBase64String(buff);
        }

        private static string CreatePasswordHash(string pwd, string salt)
        {
            string saltAndPwd = string.Concat(pwd, salt);
            string hashedPwd =
                FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(
                saltAndPwd, "sha1");
            return hashedPwd;
        }

        #endregion

        private static SqlConnection BradOnline()
        {
            UserManagerTestEntities DBContext = new UserManagerTestEntities();
            string connectionstring = DBContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
            return conn;
        }

        public List<string> groups()
        {
            List<string> groups = new List<string>();
            using (SqlConnection conn = BOnline())
            {
                using (var command = new SqlCommand("Select name from aspnet_Custom_Groups", conn))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        conn.Open();
                        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                        DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
                        adapter.Fill(dataset);
                        foreach (DataRow dr in dataset.Tables[0].Rows)
                        {
                            groups.Add(dr["name"].ToString());
                        }

                    }
                    catch (SqlException ex)
                    {
                        ex.ToString();
                    }
                    return groups;
                }
            }
        }

        public static List<string> CreateUser(Models.vw_UserManager_Model_Add_Users newUser)
        {
            List<string> outcome = new List<string>();
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection conn = BOnline())
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    UserManager.Models.vw_UserManager_Model_Add_Users model = new Models.vw_UserManager_Model_Add_Users();
                    using (var command = new SqlCommand("sp_UserManager_Add", conn))
                    {
                        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        command.Parameters.Add("@salutation", SqlDbType.NVarChar).SqlValue = newUser.salutation;
                        command.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.NVarChar).SqlValue = newUser.email;
                        command.Parameters.Add("@firstname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).SqlValue = newUser.firstname;
                        command.Parameters.Add("@lastname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).SqlValue = newUser.lastname;
                        command.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.NVarChar).SqlValue = newUser.password;

                        string salt = CreateSalt(20);
                        string passwordSalt = CreatePasswordHash(newUser.password, salt);

                        command.Parameters.Add("@passwordsalt", SqlDbType.NVarChar).SqlValue = passwordSalt;
                        command.Parameters.Add("@passwordquestion", SqlDbType.NVarChar).SqlValue = "test";
                        command.Parameters.Add("@passwordanswer", SqlDbType.NVarChar).SqlValue = "test";
                        command.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.NVarChar).SqlValue = newUser.email;
                        command.Parameters.Add("@CurrentTimeUtc", SqlDbType.DateTime).SqlValue = DateTime.UtcNow;


                        switch (newUser.isactive)
                        {
                            case true:
                                command.Parameters.Add("@isapproved", SqlDbType.TinyInt).SqlValue = 1;
                                break;
                            case false:
                                command.Parameters.Add("@isapproved", SqlDbType.TinyInt).SqlValue = 0;
                                break;
                        }

                        switch (newUser.alfConnect)
                        {
                            case true:
                                command.Parameters.Add("@Connect", SqlDbType.TinyInt).SqlValue = 1;
                                break;
                            case false:
                                command.Parameters.Add("@Connect", SqlDbType.TinyInt).SqlValue = 0;
                                break;
                        }

                        switch (newUser.alfIntelligence)
                        {
                            case true:
                                command.Parameters.Add("@Intelligence", SqlDbType.TinyInt).SqlValue = 1;
                                break;
                            case false:
                                command.Parameters.Add("@Intelligence", SqlDbType.TinyInt).SqlValue = 0;
                                break;
                        }

                        switch (newUser.brad)
                        {
                            case true:
                                command.Parameters.Add("@rad", SqlDbType.TinyInt).SqlValue = 1;
                                break;
                            case false:
                                command.Parameters.Add("@rad", SqlDbType.TinyInt).SqlValue = 0;
                                break;
                        }

                        command.Parameters.Add("@ApplicationName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).SqlValue = "bradlink";
                        command.Parameters.Add("@Group", SqlDbType.NVarChar).SqlValue = newUser.group_name;
                        int rowsCreated = command.ExecuteNonQuery();


                        if (rowsCreated > 0)
                        {
                            outcome.Add("New user created successfully.");
                            foreach (SqlParameter p in command.Parameters)
                            {
                                outcome.Add(p.Value.ToString());
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                List<string> error = new List<string>();
                error.Add("Error creating new user. Check error message for more details.");
                error.Add(ex.Message);
            }
            return outcome;
        }
    }
}
```

**My view for form submission**

```
<!-- Declare model to be used for view -->
@model UserManager.Models.vw_UserManager_Model_Add_Users 
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create New User";
}
<h2>
    CreateUser</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>New User Details</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.salutation)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.salutation)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.salutation)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.firstname)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.firstname)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.firstname)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.lastname)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.lastname)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.lastname)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.password)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.password)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.email)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.email)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.email)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.isactive)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.isactive)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.isactive)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.Label("Group Name")
            <!-- GroupName -->
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.group_name, new { ID = "group_name" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.group_name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.Label("Subscription Options")
            <!-- GroupName -->
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.Label("Connect")
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(Model => Model.Connect)
            @Html.Label("ALF Intelligence")
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(Model => Model.Intelligence)
            @Html.Label("BRAD")
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(Model => Model.rad)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" onclick="return submitWith();"/>
            <span id="validationMessage"></span>
        </p>
    </fieldset>

    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
// Count checkboxes that are checked.
    function submitWith() {
        var checkedCount = $("input:checked").length; 
        var valid = checkedCount > 0;
        if (!valid) {
            $('#validationMessage').html('You must select at least one option');
        }
        return valid;
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#group_name").autocomplete('@Url.Action("LookUpGroupName")', // Call LookUpGroupName ActionResult in UserManager Controller
        {
        dataType: 'json',
        parse: function (data) {
            var rows = new Array();
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                rows[i] = {
                    data: data[i],
                    value: data[i].group,
                    result: data[i].group
                }
            }
            return rows;
        },
        formatItem: function (row, i, max) {
            return row.group;
        },
        width: 300,
        highlight: false,
        multiple: false
    }); // End of autocomplete
});
</script>
```

Any advice for handling this?

Comment: So you're asking, how you should display an error in a View, that occurs in a Controller? I guess there's many ways to do it, depending on taste of design; but I personally would think creating a new Controller/View pairing is the wrong way to do it - rather just a new Action within the existing controller, and it can for example return a partial view, or just some json data.

Comment: @RafaelCichocki ok so would CreateUser be overloaded again but with another attribute. For example [success] so my controller knows which actionresult to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateUser(vw_UserManager_Model_Add_Users newUser)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //var data = new UserManager.Models.UserManagerTestEntities();
                // Pass model to Data Layer
                List<string> outcome =  UserManager.DAL.CreateUser(newUser);
                //data.SaveChanges();
            }
            return View();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("showError", ex.Message);
        }

    }

public ActionResult showError(String sErrorMessage)
{
    //All we want to do is redirect to the class selection page
    ViewBag.sErrMssg = sErrorMessage;
    return PartialView("ErrorMessageView");
}
```

I'd do something along these lines.

Answer (score 1):

You Can use TempData for showing the Message.
For e.g. In your controller action you can set the TempData Like

TempData["SuccessMsg"] ="Record Saved Successfully.

Then return the view you want to return and Use TempData["SuccessMsg"] in that View.

```
e.g.
@model UserManager.Models.vw_UserManager_Model_Add_Users 
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create New User";
}
<h2>
    CreateUser</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
if(TempData["SuccessMsg"]!=null)
{
<div>TempData["SuccessMsg"].ToString()</div>
}    
}
```